# How is the generic type of an Angular component captured?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, angular-material

I'm coming from imperative programming (C++, Java, C#) and am struggling to understand generics in angular components. Take for example a [Material datepicker-toggle](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/datepicker-toggle.ts).  It has a generic type argument . If I instantiate this component as follows

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

What is the type of D for the instantiated 'mat-datepicker-toggle'? How was it captured?

Answer (score 1):

Hi in angular generic behaves something like below:

```
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
    version: string;
    statusCode: number;
    result: T;
    error: string;
}
```

For mat date picker also type D will be added dynamically to that property. That means like any other generic concept based on the user given type it will be dynamically assigned to that

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I'd like to understand the specifics. How is it added dynamically? In the HTML that refers to the datepicker, how is the type inferred? What is the actual type?